# All processes have the same stack_canary?

Tags: linux-kernel

In the Linux kernel, `stack_canary` is the one of the stack protection mechanisms.

This value is generated by `boot_init_stack_canary()`. (`/init/main.c`)

`boot_init_stack_canary()` randomly generates `stack_canary` from `get_random_bytes()`.

And this canary value is referenced into task structure(`struct task`) and save in the `gs` segment register.

When a process is generated, the process gets `stack_canary` from `gs` segment.

If `stack_canary` is not refreshed anymore, all processes have the same `stack_canary` value?

Otherwise, are there any different generation methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stack canary is initialised with a random value any time a task struct is duplicated; see [`dup_task_struct()` in `kernel/fork.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/fork.c?v=4.7#L343) (and in particular [line 380](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/fork.c#L380) in version 4.7). So each forked process gets a random canary, which means there's a *very* high probability that each process has a different canary (and more importantly, you can't predict another process's stack canary).

`boot_init_stack_canary()` ensures that the first "task" (the kernel) has a stack canary. That canary isn't re-used for processes.

Comment: Linux kernel is very difficult and wide for me :( But I checked the code and exactly understood it thanks to you. Your reply is really really helpful :D Thanks a lot.